# Is that possible? How to sum a number with database column value using only Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My question is odd, but i really want to know that, how we can add(sum) a value in already saved value of database value using only query. Without any help of PHP or any other programming language.

**For Example:**
I have table like below in my database now i want to add 10 more into the column `total_students` so that `total_students` becomes 60. Is that possible or not using only query.

```
std_table
+---------+-----------------+---------------+  
  r_no      total_students    pass_students
+---------+-----------------+---------------+
  20151           50               30       
+---------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
UPDATE std_table SET total_students = total_students + 10 WHERE r_no = 20151
```

Comment: UPDATE std_table SET total_students = total_students + '$total_add' WHERE r_no = 20151

Comment: something like this

Comment: Yes, of course. You can always create a query dynamically from php. ...as long as the resulting string is a valid sql statement,

Answer (score 1):

If you are on your PHPMyAdmin panel you can run queries just like you would with any PHP query:

```
UPDATE std_table SET total_students = 60 WHERE r_no = 20151
```

or you can increment 10 to your current value on there.

```
UPDATE std_table SET total_students = total_students + 10 WHERE r_no = 20151
```

This will update all of your `total_students` to 60 where the `r_no` is equal to 20151.